# When $a$ is even, the difference between $(a/2) \mod N$ and $(a \mod N)/2$?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

folks. Could I ask for your help?

Let $N$ be a positive integer and $a$ be an even integer, i.e., $a=2x$ for an integer $x$. 
Then think of $W_N^{\frac{a}{2}}$, where $W_N=e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}}$.

Clearly the calculation is as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
W_N^{\frac{a}{2}}&=&W_N^{\frac{2x}{2}} \\
     &=&W_N^{x} \\
     &=&W_N^{(x \text{     } \text{mod} \text{     } N)}.   (1)
\end{eqnarray}

The above calculation is definitely correct.

By the way, I though of another method for the calculation.
\begin{eqnarray}
W_N^{\frac{a}{2}}&=&\left(W_N^{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
     &=&W_N^{\frac{(a \text{     } \text{mod} \text{     } N)}{2}}.   (2)
\end{eqnarray}

First, I did not understand why $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not the same generally (stupidly). After a while, I realized $(x \text{     } \text{mod} \text{     } N)$ and $\frac{(a \text{     } \text{mod} \text{     } N)}{2}$ are not the same. Actually when $(1)$ and $(2)$ are different, it seems that
\begin{equation}
   W_N^{(x \text{     } \text{mod} \text{     } N)}=(-1)W_N^{\frac{(a \text{     } \text{mod} \text{     } N)}{2}}.
\end{equation}

Be careful that sometimes (1) and (2) are the same. I mean "when the two are different", the difference is just $-1$ multiplied. Thus, 
\begin{equation}
   W_N^{(x \text{     } \text{mod} \text{     } N)}=f(a)W_N^{\frac{(a \text{     } \text{mod} \text{     } N)}{2}}. (3)
\end{equation}
where $f(a)$ is either $1$ or $-1$.

**Question) Could anybody prove (3)?**

When $N$ is odd, I could prove it by using the fact that $2$ has the multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ and let $\frac{1}{2}=b=2^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ so that $W_N^{\frac{a}{2}}=W_N^{ab}$.

But for even $N$, I couldn't do.. I hope a superman will help me....

Comment: The equation $ (a \ \mathrm{mod}\ n)/2 = (a  / 2\ \mathrm{mod}\  n)$  is generally not correct for even $n, a$. Take the example $a=8,\, n=6$ with the LHS = 1 and the RHS = 4.

Comment: What is $z^{1/2}$ when $z$ is complex (starting at "another method for the calculation")?

Answer (score 1):

If I read the question correctly, it could be restated as "Prove that for even $N$ the equality $a/2\mod n \equiv (a\mod n)/2$ holds." Assuming this was what you meant, I think you stumbled upon something very important that everyone has to realise by some point, or be told at som point, namely, what invertibility actually means.

When you write down $\frac{1}{2}$, just as a real number, what do you actually  mean? You mean another real number, say $\alpha$, such that $\alpha\cdot 2=1$. This sounds like it could be a trivial observation and maybe it is. However, when we define inverses the same way working modulo some integer $N$, this is a nice and correct definition, yet still it is where trouble may arise.

To illustrate this we look precisely at even $N=2k$. Which elements do we get when we multiply the number 2 with every element of $\mathbb{Z}_N$? The elements you get will be precisely $\{0,2,4,\ldots,2(k-1)\}$ and the important thing to notice is that $1$ is not an element of this set. This shows that it is impossible to invert the element when working modulo some even number. Can you now think why $2$ is always invertible, working modulo some odd number? In fact, we even have that $m$ is invertible modulo $N$, if and only if $\gcd(m,N)=1$.

If this was not what you tried to ask, I'm afraid I simply didn't understand your question correctly. There's also a remark I'd like to make about the previous comment by Gammatester. I strongly disagree with his comment on notation, since it confuses working in $\mathbb{Z}$ and working in $\mathbb{Z}_N$. On the left-hand side, he takes an element in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ and then pretends all of a sudden it's an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ (which it most certainly isn't!), before dividing it. On the right-hand side he does the converse thing. Once working in either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_N$, one should remain there or be very explicit otherwise. Unless one wants to utterly confuse the reader, of course.

Comment: Your comment to my comment is correct for many situations, but I simply looked at remainders of integer divisions, maybe better expressed by a function $\textrm{mod}(x,y) = x - \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor y.$ It is easy to mix-up the notations for elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_N$, as IMHO you have done with the symbols $m,2$. Using related notations for numbers and equivalence classes, as $m$ vs. $\bar{m}$ or $\lbrack m \rbrack$ helps but it is a bit clumsy: $\lbrack m \rbrack$ is invertible modulo $N$, if $\gcd(m,N)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $N=2k$ and $a=2x$ then $$(a \mod N) = \{2x+2kn: n \in \mathbb{Z} \},$$
so that ($a$ mod $N$)/$2$ consists of the integers $x+kn$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$
So since $W_N^k=-1$ you have
$$W_n^{(a \mod N)/2}=W_n^{x+kn}=W_N^x \cdot (-1)^n. $$
This will be $\pm W_n^x$ depending on the parity of $n.$